# Simplificar un documento pesado (1 GB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Estoy tratando con un modelo de Geoide, en concreto el [EGM2008](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/egm08_wgs84.html):

- Este fichero contiene la ondulación del Geoide (en metros) respecto al elipsoide WGS84, con un paso de malla de 2.5' (minutos)
- Ocupa 1.28 GB
- Ejemplo del fichero

> ```
> | LAT  | LONG  | N (Ond. Geo) |
> |------|-------|--------------|
> | 90   | 0.0   | 15           |
> | 90   | 0.4   | 15           |
> | ...  | ...   | ...          |
> | 90   | 359.8 | 15           |
> | ...  |       |              |
> | 89.8 | 0.0   | 18           |
> | ...  | ...   | ...          |
> | 89.8 | 359.8 | 15           |
> ```

Para simplificarlo, la idea es obtener un archivo con un paso de malla mayor, por ejemplo 1º (1 grado === 60 minutos). (Nota que de esta manera obtendríamos un valor de Ondulación cada grado, y tendríamos coordenadas `[longitud, latitud]` enteras:

> ```
> | LAT  | LONG  | N (Ond. Geo) |
> |------|-------|--------------|
> | 90   | 0.0   | 15           |
> | 90   | 1     | 15           |
> | ...  | ...   | ...          |
> | 90   | 359   | 15           |
> | ...  |       |              |
> | 89   | 0.0   | 18           |
> | ...  | ...   | ...          |
> | 89   | 359   | 15           |
> ```

Tengo el siguiente código, en el que hago uso de `islice`, de manera que, en un bucle while infinito:

- Leo las líneas que me interesan guardándolas en un fichero
- Leo las líneas que no me interesan, evitando guardarlas en un fichero
- Repito la operación hasta que islice no devuelva elementos

Es esta última condición es la que no me acaba de convencer ya que no me parece muy "pythonica" y me preguntaba si hay alguna manera mejor de enfocar el problema.

**NOTA**

> Hacer un readlines, cargando el Array en memoria, resulta en un
>   MemoryError

---

```
from itertools import islice

filename           = 'EGM2008_2_5min_N.dat'
paso_malla_fichero = 2.5 # En minutos
paso_malla_salida  = 60

# Cada cuantas líneas hay una longitud par
salto              = int(paso_malla_salida / paso_malla_fichero)
# Cada cuantas lineas hay una nueva latitud
salto_lat          = int(360 * (60 / paso_malla_fichero))
# Línea donde empieza un nuevo salto menos las líneas que se han leído (las que interesa extreaer)
rest_of_lines      = ( salto * salto_lat ) - (salto_lat - 1)


def parse(fileIn, fileOut):
    while True:
        lines = islice(fileIn, 0, salto_lat - 1, salto)

        try :
            fileOut.write(next(lines))
        except :
            break

        for line in lines:
            fileOut.write(line)

        for line in islice(fileIn, rest_of_lines):pass


with open(filename, 'rt') as file :
    with open('salida.txt', 'wt') as fileOut:
        parse(file, fileOut)
```

Comment: José, hay algunas cosas que no me quedan del todo claro: 1) lees bloques de 8640 líneas y recuperas 1 de cada 24 líneas, las guardas, luego 2) ignoras 198721 líneas y vuelves a retomar el ciclo. Es efectivamente lo que buscas hacer?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho La verdad es que sí, en este caso, depende obviamente de el paso de malla de entrada y del de salida. Pero, efectivamente, esa es la lógica. Por eso vi interesante el uso de islice, ya que empieza a recorrer otra vez, desde la última posición que se leyó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me queda muy claro si hay ventaja de usar `islice()` frente a una lectura secuencial normal de linea a linea, pero independientemente de esto, tal vez simplificaría un poco el código de `parse` de la siguiente forma:

```
cant_lineas_a_leer = salto_lat + rest_of_lines
lineas_a_salvar = [l for l in range(0, salto_lat, salto)]

def parse(fileIn, fileOut):

    while True:

      lines = list(islice(fileIn, cant_lineas_a_leer))
      if not lines:
          break

      fileOut.write("".join([l for i,l in enumerate(lines) if i in lineas_a_salvar]))
```

Defino una primer variable `cant_lineas_a_leer` que establece la cantidad de líneas en bloque que vamos a leer, en tu ejemplo serian 207361, de las cuales por lo que entendí, solo vas a procesar las primeras 8640 para recuperar 1 cada 24, entonces definimos una lista `lineas_a_salvar` justamente con estos números. 
De modo que al salvar solo tenemos que concatenar la lista: `[l for i,l in enumerate(lines) if i in lineas_a_salvar]` que contempla justamente la líneas que queremos.

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta. Cuando esté en casa lo pruebo y vuelvo aquí. De momento +1. Gracias :)